# DateTimeFormatter fails to parse a date in JDK 17 where as passes in JDK8

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, datetime-format, java-17

Here is the code snippet

```
String date = "Wed, 20 Feb 2019 07:14:06 +0100";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse(date, formatter).toString());
```

This code works fine with JDK8 where as fails in JDK17 with the following exception

```
Text 'Wed, 20 Feb 2019 07:14:06 +0100' could not be parsed at index 0
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Wed, 20 Feb 2019 07:14:06 +0100' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2052)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1954)
    at java.base/java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:600)
```

Comment: Specify a `Locale`.

Comment: works fine for me - maybe the default `Locale`? (it probably does not *recognize* the weekday as "Wed")

Comment: Your string is in RFC 1123 format. Just set `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME;` and parsing will succeed regardless of locale and Java version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

```java
OffsetDateTime
.parse( 
    "Wed, 20 Feb 2019 07:14:06 +0100" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME 
)
.toString()
```

> 2019-02-20T07:14:06+01:00

## Details

Your problem has nothing to do with Java 8 versus Java 17.

Tip: Before blaming software that is formally specified, is thoroughly tested by enormous test suites, and is used by millions of programmers daily, suspect your own code first.

## `Locale`

Specify a [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html). The locale determines the human language and cultural norms used in translating month names, etc.

If you do not specify a Locale, the **JVM’s current default is applied implicitly**. I would bet that when you ran your app at different times or on different machines, the JVM’s current default `Locale` varied.

```java
Locale locale = Locale.US ;
DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern( "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z" )
    .withLocale( locale );
    
String input = "Wed, 20 Feb 2019 07:14:06 +0100" ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , formatter ) ;
String output = zdt.toString() ;
System.out.println( output );
```

See this [code run at Ideone.com.](https://ideone.com/mLMItg)

> 2019-02-20T07:14:06+01:00

## RFC 1123

As [commented by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74226040/datetimeformatter-fails-to-parse-a-date-in-jdk-17-where-as-passes-in-jdk8/74226205?noredirect=1#comment131055179_74226040), your format happens to comply with the [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) standards [RFC 1123](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1123), [RFC 822](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc822/), and [RFC 2822](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc2822/).

The `DateTimeFormatter` class carries a pre-defined formatter object for that format. See the constant [`DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME).

That pre-defined formatter already has the appropriate English-based locale required by the RFCs’ specifications. So **no need to specify a `Locale`** object here.

```java
String input = "Wed, 20 Feb 2019 07:14:06 +0100" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/cDCuWr).

> 2019-02-20T07:14:06+01:00

## ISO 8601

Modern protocols use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) rather than this outdated format. The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing text or formatting a date-time instance.

I suggest you educate the publisher of your data about the virtues in using only [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats for communicating date-time values textually.

Comment: How does this code work fine without a Locale with JDK8?

Comment: @RaghuKNair There is always a `Locale`. If you do not specify a `Locale`, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. I suggest you always be explicit so the reader of your code knows your intentions.