# Date Parse Exception in Android for input Mon, 11 Sep 2023 15:49:32 GMT

Tags: android, kotlin, datetime, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing

```
 fun calculateAge(dateString: String): String {
        val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z")
        dateFormat.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")
        val inputDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString)
        val currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val inputCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        inputCalendar.time = inputDate
        val years = currentCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - inputCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val months = currentCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) - inputCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val days = currentCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - inputCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

        return when {
            years > 0 -> "$years years "
            months > 0 -> "$months months"
            else -> "$days days"
        }
    }
```

My Input of date is : Mon, 11 Sep 2023 15:49:32 GMT

i am getting this Exception : java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon, 11 Sep 2023 15:49:32 GMT"

this is piece of code using this i am trying to  calculate age its working fine till API level 33 in android but when i trying to run code using api level 34 i am getting parse exception in android can any one please help me how to fix this issue .

Comment: I recommend that you use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) for your date work. `SimpleDateFormat`, `TimeZone`, `Date` and `Calendar` are long outdated. They were supplanted by java.time a decade ago because of endless problems working with them.

Comment: I added some more tags to your question. The lack of response so far is probably partly due to people not seeing your question because the tags weren’t there. I cross my fingers that it’s not too late.

Comment: For parsing using java.time use `OffsetDateTime.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME)`. Your format agrees with what that formatter specifies. For calculating the age use `Period.between()`. It will also give you a more accurate result then what you are getting from your code.

Comment: See [Parsing RFC 2822 date in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458524/parsing-rfc-2822-date-in-java). Only promise me for your sanity that you ignore the answers using `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting error java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: (at offset 0) even if the Simple date format and string value are identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46285384/getting-error-java-text-parseexception-unparseable-date-at-offset-0-even-if) Or this? [DateTimeFormatter fails to parse a date in JDK 17 where as passes in JDK8 \[closed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74226040/datetimeformatter-fails-to-parse-a-date-in-jdk-17-where-as-passes-in-jdk8)

Comment: Thanks for solution but i am bit confused what format i need to apply please suggest

Comment: Using java.time you don’t specify any format pattern string. You just use `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`. Had you needed a format pattern stringm then the one you already used would have been correct.

Comment: I’m not really a Kotlin programmer, but I managed to put [this demonstration](https://pl.kotl.in/tu9zwy5Ii) together.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for your solution its working . can you give your answer i will accept it

Comment: Glad it works, and thanks for the invitation to write an answer. I am not writing answers on Stack Overflow for reasons that I try to explain in [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772882/ole-v-v). Feel free to write the answer yourself, and I will upvote.

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

In March 2014, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) supplanted the legacy date-time API. Since then, it has been strongly recommended to switch to `java.time`, the modern date-time API.

Your date-time string is compliant with [`DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) format. You can get the date part (`LocalDate`) out of the `OffsetDateTime`, obtained as a result of parsing the given date-time string using this `DateTimeFormatter`.

Get the current `LocalDate` at UTC and then find the period between these two dates using [`Period#between`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#between-java.time.LocalDate-java.time.LocalDate-).

```
var strDateTime = "Mon, 11 Sep 2023 15:49:32 GMT";
var dateFrom = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime, DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME)
               .toLocalDate();
var dateUntil = LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
var period = Period.between(dateFrom, dateUntil);
System.out.println(period);

// Formatted
System.out.println(formattedPeriod(period));
```

where `formattedPeriod(Period)` is a function returning a `String` formatted in your desired manner.

```
String formattedPeriod(Period period) {
    var years = period.getYears();
    var months = period.getMonths();

    return years > 0 ? years + " years" : months > 0 ? months + " months" : period.getDays() + " days";
}
```

**Output:**

```
P27D
27 days
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/Xf2S1q)

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**

**Note:** My area of expertise is Java and therefore I have written the code using Java language. Kotlin supports running Java code as it is. A Kotlin programmer can easily translate a Java code into the corresponding Kotlin code. Moreover, most part of my code can be reused as it is in the corresponding Kotlin program.

### Update

Since your date-time string is in GMT/UTC, I have used `LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)` to get the current `LocalDate` in GMT/UTC i.e. the key is to get the `LocalDate` using the same time zone offset as your data-time string.

As commented by Ole V.V., you can explicitly apply a time zone offset to the parsed date-time and the current `LocalDate`. He has also provided a link to the solution in Kotlin using his approach. [Here](https://ideone.com/9ng9Se) is the link to the code in Java using his approach.

Comment: Since the string may contain any UTC offset, in [my code](https://pl.kotl.in/tu9zwy5Ii) I converted the parsed `OffsetDateTime` to the default time zone and did the age calculation there. With the example string you are getting both dates in GMT or UTC (which for this purpose is the same), but I wanted to make sure I always use the same time zone. Mentioned for possible inspiration.